# Подкючение Android к MySQL

Tags: android

Вот к примеру есть написаный на PHP Mysql чат и каждый раз , как пишу в чат  то должно приходить уведомление на андроид приложение о написаном сообщение.
Подскажите пожалуйта, как это сделать, то в интернете мало информации.(Желательно пример кода)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Говорить о подключении android приложения напрямую к базе mysql не очень логично. Это и проблемы с конектом и с библиотеками для клиента. Да и безопастность - данные для коннекта будут у вас в приложении. А "выковырнуть" их оттуда особого труда не составит.

Я вижу два варианта решения задачи:

1. Периодически подключаться из приложения на какой-то URL сервера где находится чат и получать оттуда данные об бновлениях. На стороне сервера это может быть тот же PHP скрипт, который будет отдавать результа, например, в JSON
2. Из скрипта чата на PHP посылать PUSH уведмоления, которые уже будут приходить в приложение. Можно как свой велосипед сгородить, так и использоватьготовые сервисы.